# JAVA regex to get entire json from text

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a text inside which i have a valid json i want to extract entire json using regex. I am able to do it in **javascript with simple regex** : `{.*}` but not in java. I want a java compatible regex.

Sample Text with valid json:

```
data:""{"_id": {"$oid": "gdgdgdr"},"code": "grdgd34","name": "name1","desc": "desc","transRefId": "5debeeed8df45b0314569caa","origAmount": 1000,"amount": 1000,"currency": "USD","redeemedCashcode": "dwdw","sender": {"id": "FESFS","name": "rose","phone": "3424234232"},"receiver": {"id": "5d04c70c65c79dedb21080e1","name": "Move money from bank to wallet","phone": "63454332422","client": "biller"},"beneficiary": {},"depositor": {},"offer": "42efsgf"}""
```

Regex I have tried in java is : `\\{.*\\}`

How will i achieve the same in JAVA?

Comment: Can you share what you have done in java ?

Comment: {.*} is giving "Unable to execute regular expression. java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition {.*}" error

Comment: i have updated the question with it @soorapadman

Comment: Can you show your Java code in question.

Comment: I intend to use this regex in wso2sp , as this platform is java based, regex needs to be in JAVA format , i am testing the above regex on https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

Answer (score 2):

Your regular expression works perfectly fine in Java, of course.

However, you should not match the entire string, you should search for the match *inside* the string, and for that you use `Matcher#find` (as there is no convenience method in `String` itself):

```java
String data = "data:\"\"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"gdgdgdr\"},\"code\": \"grdgd34\",\"name\": \"name1\",\"desc\": \"desc\",\"transRefId\": \"5debeeed8df45b0314569caa\",\"origAmount\": 1000,\"amount\": 1000,\"currency\": \"USD\",\"redeemedCashcode\": \"dwdw\",\"sender\": {\"id\": \"FESFS\",\"name\": \"rose\",\"phone\": \"3424234232\"},\"receiver\": {\"id\": \"5d04c70c65c79dedb21080e1\",\"name\": \"Move money from bank to wallet\",\"phone\": \"63454332422\",\"client\": \"biller\"},\"beneficiary\": {},\"depositor\": {},\"offer\": \"42efsgf\"}\"\"";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{.*\\}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
matcher.find();
System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

Prints:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "gdgdgdr"},"code": "grdgd34","name": "name1","desc": "desc","transRefId": "5debeeed8df45b0314569caa","origAmount": 1000,"amount": 1000,"currency": "USD","redeemedCashcode": "dwdw","sender": {"id": "FESFS","name": "rose","phone": "3424234232"},"receiver": {"id": "5d04c70c65c79dedb21080e1","name": "Move money from bank to wallet","phone": "63454332422","client": "biller"},"beneficiary": {},"depositor": {},"offer": "42efsgf"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and your regexp works, here is the test and result

```
final String regex = "\\{.*\\}";
    final String string = "data:\"\"{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"gdgdgdr\"},\"code\": \"grdgd34\",\"name\": \"name1\",\"desc\": \"desc\",\"transRefId\": \"5debeeed8df45b0314569caa\",\"origAmount\": 1000,\"amount\": 1000,\"currency\": \"USD\",\"redeemedCashcode\": \"dwdw\",\"sender\": {\"id\": \"FESFS\",\"name\": \"rose\",\"phone\": \"3424234232\"},\"receiver\": {\"id\": \"5d04c70c65c79dedb21080e1\",\"name\": \"Move money from bank to wallet\",\"phone\": \"63454332422\",\"client\": \"biller\"},\"beneficiary\": {},\"depositor\": {},\"offer\": \"42efsgf\"}\"\"";

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    matcher.find();
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

and the result is:

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "gdgdgdr"},"code": "grdgd34","name": "name1","desc": "desc","transRefId": "5debeeed8df45b0314569caa","origAmount": 1000,"amount": 1000,"currency": "USD","redeemedCashcode": "dwdw","sender": {"id": "FESFS","name": "rose","phone": "3424234232"},"receiver": {"id": "5d04c70c65c79dedb21080e1","name": "Move money from bank to wallet","phone": "63454332422","client": "biller"},"beneficiary": {},"depositor": {},"offer": "42efsgf"}
```

java has not any specific standard for regexp. `\\{.*\\}` -is just string escaped regular expression. In java character `\` is used to escape some special characters, so if you want to use this char into string as regular character it must be also escaped with extra `\`. `String a = "\\"` resolves to String which will have only one `\`. 
so **`"\\{.*\\}"`** resolves to a regular expression "`\{.*\}`" where `\` are also an escape characters for egexp processor to deal with `{ and }` as  symbols and not as special chars